# The type or namespace name 'IgnoreDataMember' could not be found

Tags: twitter, twitterizer

I am getting this error while using the twitterizer API:

> The type or namespace name 'IgnoreDataMember' could not be found

I have downloaded the API source code, but I haven't been able to resolve the error.

Answer (score 4):

You need a reference to System.Runtime.Serialization (and possibly other things) to compile.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Visual Studio 2008? What kind of application are you trying to build?

The IgnoreDataMember attribute is used by the JSON serialization class. It is used to decorate properties of a class that should not be expected when deserializing an object from json, nor should be included when serializing the object to json.

As of now, the Twitterizer library does not support Silverlight or the Compact Framework. Both are planned, but time is limited.